# Issues reading and filtering the lines of a string

Tags: powershell

I am moving away from a user creation script that used to rely on a .txt input file. Now I want to pull the info direct from the Jira Ticket.

To avoid redoing the entire script, I would like the `$inputfile` to no longer be the .txt file, but the `$ticket.description`.

The `$ticket.description` looks like this:

```
Vorname:  Adam
Nachname: Tester
Anstellungsart: Festangestellter
Job-Bezeichnung: IT-Guy
Unternehmen: StackOverFlow
Abteilung: ITS
```

And the code to read it, at least to start with:

```
$TicketKey = Read-Host "Please enter the Onboarding Ticket Key for this user"
$Ticket = Get-JiraIssue -Key $TicketKey
$Inputfile = $ticket.description | Out-String -Stream
$VornameDis = $inputfile | ?{$_ -like "*Vorname*"} | %{$_.split(":")[1]} | %{$_.trim()}
$NachnameDis = $inputfile | ?{$_ -like "*Nachname*"} | %{$_.split(":")[1]} | %{$_.trim()}
```

However for either $VornameDis or $NachnameDis, the output is always:

```
Adam
Nachname
```

I think there is an issue with the `Out-String -Stream` not breaking up the input by line break, but cannot be sure. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What's the type of `$inputfile`? Use `.GetType()` method to find out.

Comment: `$inputfile = $inputfile -split '\r?\n'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, that was the solution! Thank you very much! How does this work though?

Answer (score 1):

The output from `[some-value-expression] |Out-String -Stream` will be a single string per input element - and since `$ticket.description` is probably already just one string, you end up with `$inputfile` being one big multi-line string.

In order to filter on each line as a separate string we first need to split it up on new line characters:

```
$intputfile = $inputfile -split '\r?\n'
$VornameDis = $inputfile | ?{$_ -like "*Vorname*"} | %{$_.split(":")[1]} | %{$_.trim()}
$NachnameDis = $inputfile | ?{$_ -like "*Nachname*"} | %{$_.split(":")[1]} | %{$_.trim()}
```

Although I suspect you could skip `Out-String` completely and do:

```
$inputfile = $ticket.description -split '\r?\n'
$VornameDis = $inputfile | ?{$_ -like "*Vorname*"} | %{$_.split(":")[1]} | %{$_.trim()}
...
```